# Using Container Builder Build Triggers in repository with multiple projects

Tags: google-container-registry

I have a single Cloud Source Repository with multiple projects.  I am able to create a cloudbuild.yaml file in the repo root that builds all projects.  However, I don't want to have a build trigger that rebuilds all of the projects since most commits will be for a single project.    Ideally I would like to have a cloudbuild.yaml file in each project subdirectory and a build trigger that detects changes in the project subdirectory of the repository.  Is something like this possible?

As a possible workaround, I believe I may be able to keep my cloudbuild.yaml in the repository root and create a custom step that will get the commit sha (via the COMMIT_SHA substitution) and then get the list of files committed (via "git show --name-only --pretty=format: $COMMIT_SHA") to determine which project should be built and what image should be created.  An alternative may be to have a tagging naming convention that will contain the project name and basing the trigger on that but I don't want to tag each commit.

Note, it seems like build triggers work very well when you have multiple repos but we made the decision to go with a mono repo and I don't want to rehash that debate in this question.  I'd like to understand how to best use the Build Triggers in a mono repo.

Comment: Thanks for this useful feedback. Today, triggers can only be run from the root of the repo, and this is a known limitation of the service. Allowing triggers to be run from subdirectories would help bring better support for monorepos like yours. Unfortunately we don't have a good story for this today. Of the two options you describe, the tagging scheme seems slightly better, though I agree it's not optimal.

Comment: Did you found a solution to this limitation? cc @JasonHall has anything changed?

Comment: GCB triggers can now define paths that should and should not trigger a build, which can help with this somewhat. Define a trigger that builds Component A from source dir for A, and only triggers on changes to that dir, etc.